# My text is overlapping with my components (React, CSS)

Tags: html, css, formatting, algolia

I'm trying to format my CSS so that when someone makes their screen smaller, the text doesn't overlap with the search component underneath.

[With overlap (undesired)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjRnG.png)

[Without overlap (desired)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGmSN.png)

Is there any elegant way to do this other than manually changing the text width based upon the size of the screen? (e.g., responsive media queries).

Answer (score 1):

Media queries, what’s your problem with it ?..  if you prefer less writing use tail-wind .. it will make that easier without writing media queries yourself.

Comment: feel free to choose it as an answer